# Show only account numbers with different pointTypes

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-server-2008

I will try to explain what I was asked to do to the best of my ability.

Let's say that we have developer access to DataBase **A**, which has many tables inside, but we are mostly concerned about two tables. The first one is called **Accounts**, and the second one **Campaign**. Now, inside the Campaign table we have many fields, but the most important are *CampaignTypeID*, and *AccountID*.

Inside the **Accounts** table the most important field are *AccountID*, and *CustomerNumber*. In the **Accounts** table we have many customers who have participated in different campaigns; therefore we can say that a single costumer can have many different CampaignTypeIDs under their account.

Now here is what I was asked to do: **Show one CustomerNumber for each CampaignTypeID** (5 types total). (I think that repeated CustomerNumbers are acceptable)
(Ex.)

```
CampaignTypeID  CustomerNumber
1                   34535
2                   23525
3                   23423
4                   52355
5                   23525
```

This is the query I used:

```
SELECT top 5 CustomerNumber[Customer Number],  CampaignTypeID , 
 FROM A.Account a
  JOIN A.Campaign c  ON a.AccountID = c.AccountID
  WHERE CampaignTypeID IN (5)
  GROUP BY CustomerNumber, CampaignTypeID
```

The result of this query would be something like:
(Ex.)

```
CampaignTypeID  CustomerNumber
    5                34535
    5                23525
    5                23423
    5                52355
    5                23525
```

Not exactly what I wanted, at first I plugged in all of the CampaignTypeIDs into the WHERE clause, but that would only return repeated CampaignTypeIDs.
(Ex.)

```
CampaignTypeID  CustomerNumber
        3            34535
        3            23525
        4            23423
        5            52355
        5            56678
        3            23525
```

As you can see at this point my only option was to enter each CampaignTypeID, one by one. Then I would copy each one of those to a spread sheet. What I showed you above was just an example, but what I had to do had actually 40 different CampaignTypeIDs. It was a very tedious job that I know can be made A LOT more efficient.

If possible I would like to know a more efficient way to complete this task.

Thanks!

UPDATE: Alright, a small thing I should have added. The CampaignTypeID are not sequential, they are more like 5,6,7,8,9,10,50,65,110,250,1104,1114. Would this complicate thing?

**SCHEMA**

```
CREATE TABLE Accounts 
    (
     AccountID int auto_increment primary key, 
     CustomerID int(20)NOT NULL
    );

INSERT INTO Accounts
(CustomerID)
VALUES
(24),(22),(35),(256),(1246),(11),(224),(55),(664),(773),(234),(568),(245),(986),(768);



CREATE TABLE Campaign 
    (
     CampaignID int auto_increment primary key, 
     CampaignTypeID int(20) NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT fk_AccountID FOREIGN KEY(AccountID)
     REFERENCES Accounts(AccountID) 
    );

INSERT INTO Campaign
(CampaignTypeID)
VALUES
(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(245),(1140),(1150),(1160),(1170),(1180),(1190),(1240),(1250),(1260);
```

Comment: You might want to accept answers to some of the other questions you've asked, it might make more people willing to help you.  Also, are you trying to show one row for each `CampaignTypeId`, with a _single_ customer for each of the `CampaignTypeId`s?  If there are multiple, what's the criteria to choose between them (ie - is just using `MAX(CustomerNumber)` good enough)?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't able to look at this during the weekend, so I couldn't give feedback to the people wiling to help me, sorry again. Back on topic; Yes, I want to show a single customer for each CampaignTypeId. I tried what was suggested below, and it didn't work.

Comment: Your campaign table has a reference from `AccountID`, but no `AccountID` column

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand what you mean. What else do I need to reference?

Answer (score 0):

```
Select
  CampaignTypeID,
  Min(CustomerNumber)
From
  A.Account a
    Inner Join
  A.Campaign c
    On a.AccountID = c.AccountID
Where
  CampaignTypeID Between 1 And 5
Group By
  CampaignTypeID
```

Comment: Hi, I tried what you suggested and it didn't work, I still get repeated CampaignTypeIDs. I am looking for a result that will only show ONE member for each CampaignTypeID. Also the CampaignTypeIDs are not sequential, they are more like this:  5,6,7,8,9,10,50,65,110,250,1104,1114. THANKS!

Comment: Go to http://sqlfiddle.com/ and type in some example tables and data, and link back here when you are done.

Comment: Hi, I updated my opening statement with the schema I would have used.